# File extension for html snippet

Tags: html, text-files, file-extension, dynamically-generated

My program generates html documents based on parameters, but one part is static and is fetched from a local text file.

What file extension would it be appropriate for such a snippet to have?

**htm(l):** it is not really a proper html document, since it has no `<html>` tag etc.

**txt:** it is not really a plain text file either.

**Something else?**

Comment: It don't mind which ending you use. Because no application (except yours) has to handle the file. I would suggest to end the file with "tpl" (like template) or something.

Comment: Actually I face a similar problem. The files have to be accessible for AJAX / SSI, but shuould not be indexed by robots, so a different file ending would be rather smart.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to denote with the extension in which context you can use the snippet:

.xhtml is for application/xhtml+xml documents
.html is for text/html documents

But as already noted, this is just informal.